# XFS filesystem over 1 PB in size

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

My business requirements (licensing) require me to create a single XFS filesystem of over 1 PB with potential to grow to 2-3 PB in the future.  This is to use as a backup repository so lots of streaming writes and few random reads.

is there any reason not to do this specifically using XFS? Red Hat's documentation suggests an XFS filesystem should have no trouble growing to 10x it's creation size, so that sounds reasonable.  1 PB is well under the XFS supported maximum.

Comment: What operating system, hardware, and distribution?

Comment: @ewwhite my question is hardware agnostic.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work... if you're building something that large, technical detail matter.

Comment: @ewwhite Your observation is correct.  This question is not a consultation request on how to build something this large, but whether there are good real world reasons to avoid XFS for file systems of 1PB or larger.  My apologies if that is not clear.